# Wie nennt man eine Anzeige aus mehreren Lämpchen?

Tags: single-word-request, synonym

[image: Auf diesem Gerät] 
Auf diesem Gerät ist eine Anzeige in Form eines "Lampenstrahls". Je nachdem, welcher Wert erreicht wird, leuchten unterschiedlich viele Lämpchen. Gibt es ein deutsches, verständliches Wort für so etwas? Es erinnert mich an einen Zahlenstrahl, deswegen "Lampenstrahl", aber wirklich passen tut es nicht... Zur Not nehme ich auch den englischen Fachbegriff, falls es einen gibt.

Comment: +1 for bringing me a medical company into attention that uses hearts as it was a producer of erotic videos.

Comment: Schade - von der Überschrift her würde ich sagen "Cockpit", aber das Bild und der Text erlauben das leider nicht. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Das ist eine

> [LED-Balkenanzeige](http://de.farnell.com/kingbright/dc-20-20gwa/balkenarray-20-segmente-gr-n-2/dp/2314212)

(Link führt auf eine kommerzielle Seite, wo man sowas kaufen kann. Natürlich kann man sowas auch woanders kaufen) Ziemlich direkt übernommen aus dem Englischen *bar graph* - oder (seltener) eine

> Leuchtbandanzeige

Comment: Warum nicht direkt [Bargraph-Anzeige](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bargraph-Anzeige)? Da muss man nix kaufen ;)

Comment: Weil es ein schönes deutsches Wort gibt. Da muss man nix Englisches nehmen.

Comment: So schön deutsch ist LED nun nicht gerade. War auch nur ein Vorschlag den Kommerzlink zu vermeiden und Auf die gute alte WP und ihren Standardsetzungsmachtmechanismus zu vertrauen. Ohne das Gerät im Bild in Aktion zu sehen, halte ich übrigens "Band" für vielleicht nicht ganz passend. Gibt es da nicht noch was aus der Bürokratenstube, a la Ampel?

Comment: @tofro: Da gebe ich dir recht, aber dann sag' doch gleich *Leuchtdioden-Balkenanzeige.* *LED* ist auch Englisch (light emitting diode).

Comment: @RudyVelthuis *LED* geht schon als deutsche Abkürzung für *LEuchtDiode* durch und ist eingebürgert genug, meiner Ansicht nach.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis oder noch besser nur "Balkenanzeige", weil es auf das Leuchtmittel gar nicht ankommt.

Comment: @Gerhardh Hmm. Nur "Balkenanzeige" verliert halt gegenüber der "LED-Balkenanzeige" die Implikation, dass Letztere nur diskrete Werte anzeigen kann. Das kann wichtig sein oder auch nicht.

Comment: @tofro würdest du eine Balkenanzeige aus Glühbirnen, zweifarbigen Klappelementen oder e-Ink auch als LED-Balkenanzeige bezeichnen? Diskrete Werte würde auf alle drei Varianten zutreffen.

Comment: @Gerhardh Der "magische Balken" aus einem alten Röhrenradio oder der "Säulentacho" aus einem alten Heckflossen-Mercedes waren auch  "Balkenanzeigen" - konnten aber kontinuierliche Werte anzeigen. Wenn du nur Beispiele wählst, die nur diskrete Werte anzeigen können, passt dein Begriff natürlich.

Comment: @Gerhardh: aber dann wäre eine LCD-Balkenanzeige auch gemeint, und das war wohl nicht die Frage.

Answer (score 7):

Ich würde das in den meisten Alltagskontexten wohl eine

> Skala

nennen, oder zur genaueren Beschreibung auch eine

> Leuchtskala

oder eine

> LED-Skala

oder, wenn's etwas technophiler sein soll, eine

> Leuchtdiodenskala

Comment: Dachte ich auch erst dran: Ist Leuchtskala nicht etwas passiver, früher gern mit Radium, ein phosphoreszierendes Etwas?

Comment: @LangLangC  Ich fasse es so auf: Leuchtskala ist alles, was eine Skala zeigt (eine Reihe von inkrementellen Anzeigewerten) und leuchtet. Welche Leuchttechnik verwendet wird, hängt halt davon ab, was die Zeit, der Ort und die Technologie gerade dafür anbieten. Man könnte sich vorstellen zu gegebener Zeit am gegebenen Ort eine Leuchtskala mit Kerzen einzurichten. (Z.B. Mädchen stellt 1, 2, 3... Kerzen ins Fenster, um zu signalisieren, wie dringend sie ihren Liebsten zu Besuch haben will.)

Comment: An sich ist es schon so, dass eine Skala alleine nichts anzeigen kann - IEs ist ja der Zeiger, der das tut. Die Balkenanzeige kann aber auch ohne Zeiger was anzeigen - Daher finde ich, dass "Skala" nicht ganz passt, bzw. nur eine Hälfte des Dings beschreibt.